# Can a stemming dictionary be used as rejection criteria in R?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I am struggling through some text analysis, and I'm not sure I'm doing the stemming correctly. Right now, my command for single-term stemming is

```
text_stem <- text_clean %>% mutate(stem = wordStem(word, language = "english"))
```

Is it possible to use this not only as a stemmer, but as a filter? For example, if "text_clean" contains the word aksdjhgla and that word is not in whatever SnowballC uses as a dictionary, the stemmed text would reject it? Maybe there's another command that does this kind of filtering?

Comment: There are many different things that could be causing the problems you are having. I would encourage including the actual error you're receiving and making your code reproducible. Refs: [stackoverflow.com/q/5963269](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)

Comment: @Kat, I'm not getting an error. The code works as it should (I think). When I look at the top n stems, I'm wondering if I can use the stemmer to reject "garbage" (or misspelled) words.

Comment: How about this resource? [This is a link to the `hunspell` package content explanation.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hunspell/vignettes/intro.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wordStem` does not employ a dictionary but uses grammatical rules to do stemming (which is a rather crude approximation to lemmatisation btw). Here is an example:

```r
words <- c("win", "winning")
words2 <- c("aksdjhglain", "aksdjhglainning")

SnowballC::wordStem(words, language = "english")
#> [1] "win"    "win"
SnowballC::wordStem(words2, language = "english")
#> [1] "aksdjhglain"  "aksdjhglain"
```

As you can see, `wordStem` does exactly the same, no matter if the words actually exist or are complete rubbish. All that matters are the word endings (ie stems). As @Kat suggested, you probably want to look at the `hunspell` package which actually uses dictionaries. To find out which words exist in the dictionary, use `hunspell_check`:

```
hunspell::hunspell_check(c(words, words2))
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

Inside your existing code, you could use this to remove misspelled words:

```
text_stem <- text_clean %>% 
  mutate(stem = wordStem(word, language = "english")) %>% 
  filter(hunspell::hunspell_check(word), dict = dictionary("en_US"))
```